# How to disable importing authtoken.models when using SessionAuthentication with django-rest-framework?

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework

In my rest_framework settings I set SessionAuthentication as the default authentication class

```
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
)
```

The problem is that my User DELETE api view tries to collapse delete on the authtoken_token table, which doesn't exist (since I don't need it), raising a database exception.

Specifically, when obj.delete() is invoked in DestroyModelMixin.destroy, this exception is raised:

```
DatabaseError: relation "authtoken_token" does not exist
LINE 1: ...oken"."user_id", "authtoken_token"."created" FROM "authtoken...
```

Is one required to syncdb rest_framework's models, even if one doesn't need them?

Is there a way to use SessionAuthentication without including authtoken.models?

Am I doing something wrong?

(removing authtoken.models.Token completely from rest_framework/authentication.py seems to solve the problem)

Comment: Nope, you don't need to `syncdb` unless you've explicitly installed `rest_framework.authtoken` in your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting.

Have you accidentally got that in your `INSTALLED_APPS`, or have you unintentionally created a ForeignKey or other relationship to it?  What's the full traceback?

Comment: I do not explicitly install rest_framework.authtoken in my INSTALLED_APPS (only rest_framework). But I am beginning to suspect that there is some automagic happening in the background of our fairly complex django project. Any ideas on how to debug this? Here's the traceback from DestroyModelMixin on: https://gist.github.com/nejcjelovcan/5dc47eea7134e12f5d6b

Comment: What's the model definition of the model that view is using?

Comment: Apparently, this only happens in tests, when I do a DELETE request with django.test.client.Client (which afaik mocks the actual HTTP requests), and only if rest_framework.authentication is imported within the test.

Actual HTTP DELETE request to API works as intended (no exception raised for missing authtoken_token when deleting User).

I will try to reproduce the behaviour in a clean django project, since this one is too complex for me to adequately describe it here.

Thanks for all the help and for this great framework!

Comment: The approach I would use is create a custom middleware, import the `settings.'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES` variable and set the changes needed based on sessions. This is the most obvious thing I think is the best.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the root cause...

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/19422

Will sort out a workaround in the meantime, which will probably just involve making sure `Token` doesn't get imported anywhere unless `rest_framework.authtoken` is in `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: If anyone encounters this issue, tom fixed it in [this revision](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/commit/c5b98f0d106758298edf045e7bb44ecd7e4b9629) and the simplest solution is to upgrade version to 2.2.4 (or above)

Answer (score 0):

Please use ‍‍‍‍‍`python manage.py migrate` command after you install **`rest_framework.authtoken`** even `python manage.py makemigrations` command says No changes detected.